# Installation problems with Visitor

Tags: install, visitor, mysqli

With EE2, Zoo Visitor was easy to install.

the lack of documentation makes it very difficult to install Visitor on EE3.

Here the copy of the screen installer.[image]

Without the documentation I can't understand this error message:
[image]

> An anonymous Guest member does not exist or is not linked with Visitor, go to the Visitor settings and select a member you want to use as anonymous Guest member.

I don't understand this error message too, because Visitor has created and anonymous Guest member.[image: error message about the anonymous Guest Member]

If I click on install this messager error appears:
[image]

The settings options is not working.
Does someone already has ever encountered these problems?

> **Updated Question with theses errror screenshots**

**Here more details about error message when i click on install, I tried to manually one by one each step, but But I can not do it.**

The error screenshots under the

```
Expcetion Caught mesage
```

[image: errors messages]

Comment: Are you using php7?

Comment: Hi Mufi, yes it's PHP 7.1. But I tried  after with PHP 5.65, it was the same problem.  I will try install it using PHP 5.65. Thanks

Comment: Using PHP 5.6 the problem still the same.

Comment: I've just installed Visitor on an external server, and it works fine. So, the problem is a local Wamp server configuration. But I confess I don't know what are the wrong parameters. (WampServer Version 3.0.8 64bit, Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 7.1.0, MySQL 5.7.14).

Comment: Visitor module is not compatible with php7.. it should work on wamp or xamp if you run php 5.3.8 or something similar version. Sometimes guest member is not linked automatically. We have to create one and assign him.

Comment: Even on PHP 5.3.8 on Wamp, the problem still the same. On the external server, it's PHP 7, Visitor works fine. The PHP 7 installation error was fixed, changelog: VISITOR 3.0.1
Released: May 09, 2016
ADDED: ExpressionEngine 3.3.0 support
BUG: Installation would produce an error in PHP 7. So I guess, it must be a Wamp configuration problem. In my external, server the installation under PHP 7 Did not create any problems. The guest member was created by Visitor using Wamp, how to assign him manually??  Which SQL table should I change? To assign manually the member to Visitor?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. What I did is to manually create these fields on Visitor Fields group:

- [**Field Name | Shortname | Field Type | Options**]
- Member account | member_account | visitor | n/a
- Firstname | member_firstname | text | n/a
- Lastname | member_lastname | text | n/a
- Gender | member_gender | radio | 'Male' & 'Female' on Radio options
- Birthday | member_birthday | date | n/a

when I created these fields and refresh the install page (or click the start install button), all status is now Done.

Note: This solution is only to be able to continue on the setup and not a permanent solution for the actual problem with the addon. I'm not very good programmer I just tried doing this and it worked. Just sharing it.

Comment: Hi Neetcoder, thanks for your solution. have you experienced this issue on a local server (Wamp)? When I installed Visitor 3.0.1 on an external server )(Apache PHP 7) I didn't encountered problems with the installation,  I guess it must be a server configuration problem. So if I don't find the right configuration server  under Wamp, I will use your solution.

Comment: It happened on both my local server (Ubuntu, PHP 7.1.5) and external server (PHP 7.1.6). I didn't spend much time to it, I'm on a tight schedule.